# How to place text below boxes

Tags: html, css

I have placed two boxes next to each other and now I want to place some text directly underneath the boxes. The HTML/CSS I have so far keeps placing the text in the top right corner of the right hand box. Any suggestions?

```html
<div id="one-off-pricing" style="width:800px;">
    
    <div id="one-off-pricing-1" style="width:370px;height:400px;border:   1px solid #cecece;float:left;margin-left:270px;margin-top:20px;">
    
    <div id="one-off-pricing-2" style="width:370px;height:400px;border: 1px solid #cecece;float:left;margin-left:370px;margin-top:-1px;">
    </div>
   </div>
   
   <span style="font-weight:bold;"> *If for any reason we're unable to complete the job we'll give you a full refund, no questions asked.</span> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block;` on `<span>`.

Like:

```
span  {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="one-off-pricing" style="width:800px;">
    
    <div id="one-off-pricing-1" style="width:370px;height:400px;border:   1px solid #cecece;float:left;margin-left:270px;margin-top:20px;">
    
    <div id="one-off-pricing-2" style="width:370px;height:400px;border: 1px solid #cecece;float:left;margin-left:370px;margin-top:-1px;">
    </div>
   </div>
   
   <span style="font-weight:bold;"> *If for any reason we're unable to complete the job we'll give you a full refund, no questions asked.</span> 
    </div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better version, with the actual boxes next to eachother, instead of inside eachother and moved via margins.

```html
<div id="one-off-pricing" style="width:800px; overflow: hidden;">
    <div id="one-off-pricing-1" style="width:370px;height:400px;border: 1px solid #cecece;float: left;margin-top:20px;">
    </div>
    <div id="one-off-pricing-2" style="width:370px;height:400px;border: 1px solid #cecece;display: inline-block;margin-top: 20px;">
    </div>
</div>
   
   <p style="font-weight:bold;"> *If for any reason we're unable to complete the job we'll give you a full refund, no questions asked.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<div id="one-off-pricing" style="width:800px;">
    
    <div id="one-off-pricing-1" style="width:370px;height:400px;border:   1px solid #cecece;float:left;margin-left:270px;margin-top:20px;">
    
    <div id="one-off-pricing-2" style="width:370px;height:400px;border: 1px solid #cecece;float:left;margin-left:370px;margin-top:-1px;">
    </div>
   </div>
   
   <span style="font-weight:bold;clear:both;display:block;"> *If for any reason we're unable to complete the job we'll give you a full refund, no questions asked.</span> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (and see the notes and explanations below):

```css
.one-off-pricing {
width: 800px;
}

.one-off-pricing div {
display:inline-block;
width:370px;
height:400px;
border:1px solid #cecece;
}

p {
font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="one-off-pricing">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<p>*If for any reason we're unable to complete the job we'll give you a full refund, no questions asked.</p>
</div>
```

**1) Why put all the inline CSS in a stylesheet?**

It massively helps with scaling and maintenance.

**2) Why use a `class` for "one-off-pricing" instead of an `id`?**

When CSS selectors start to get long and complex, `ids` in long chained selectors can mess things up. For this reason it's often (not always but often) better to use a `class` instead of an `id`.

**3) Why use `<p>` instead of a `<span>`?**

Because the element in question is best described as a paragraph.

**4) Why use *display:inline-block* instead of a float?**

Because you simply don't need `floats` in this situation.